# How to capture 5 lines after Regex match using python

Tags: python, regex

I Have a text starting with 3 digits of code I have written a logic to capture the current line but I need to capture the next 5 lines continuously

```
import re
newtxt="200 sample text with many lines\n hell01 \n hell02 \n hell03 \n hell04 \n hell05\n hell06\n hell07 \n hell08"
text = re.compile(r'^\d{3} [a-z].*')
for line in newtxt.split('\n'):
       if text.match(line):
            print(line)
```

Comment: Please check [my updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62801586/3832970).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `iter`

**Ex:**

```
import re
newtxt="200 sample text with many lines\n hell01 \n hell02 \n hell03 \n hell04 \n hell05\n hell06\n hell07 \n hell08"
text = re.compile(r'^\d{3} [a-z].*')
newtext = iter(newtxt.splitlines())
for line in newtext:
    if text.match(line):
        for _ in range(5):
            print(next(newtext))
```

**Output:**

```
 hell01 
 hell02 
 hell03 
 hell04 
 hell05
```

---

If you are reading this from a file object you will not require `iter` method. You can directly iterate the lines.

**Ex:**

```
text = re.compile(r'^\d{3} [a-z].*')
with open(filename) as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if text.match(line):
            for _ in range(5):
                print(next(infile))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
r'(?m)^\d{3} [a-z].*((?:\r?\n.*){0,5})'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7CttLN/1). Note `(?m)` can be replaced with `re.M` flag in the code.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `\d{3} [a-z]` - three digits, space and a lowercase letter
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `((?:\r?\n.*){0,5})` - Group 1: zero to five repetitions of the line break and then the rest of the line.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/HFDKbM):

```
import re
newtxt="200 sample text with many lines\n hell01 \n hell02 \n hell03 \n hell04 \n hell05\n hell06\n hell07 \n hell08"
pattern = re.compile(r'^\d{3} [a-z].*((?:\r?\n.*){0,5})', re.M)
m = pattern.search(newtxt)
if m:
  print( m.group(1) )
```

Output:

```
 hell01 
 hell02 
 hell03 
 hell04 
 hell05
```