# How to capture 5 lines after Regex match from a multiple file using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

I have found a suggestion for my queries from the below link but it's for a single file but I want to read multiple file to match a pattern

[How to capture 5 lines after Regex match using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62798403/how-to-capture-5-lines-after-regex-match-using-python)

Below is my code:
next is iterating for one time and getting below error:

File "./noimages_rep.py", line 34, in noimage_jobs
err=(next(myfile))
StopIteration

Need help/suggestion to capture 5 lines after Regex match from a multiple file  on the give path

```
pattern=re.compile(r'(?:Exit(.*)\sfound)',re.MULTILINE)

matches=[]
t_jobs=[]
past=80*60*60
def noimage_jobs():
    path="/tmp/noimages_backup/"
    for p,d,f in os.walk(path):
        if len(f)!=0:
            for each_file in f:
                #print(each_file)
                file_path=(os.path.join(p,each_file))
                if os.path.getmtime(file_path) >= past:
                    with open(file_path, 'r') as myfile:
                        if re.search(pattern,str(line)) !=None:
                            for _ in range(5):
                                err=(next(myfile))
                                print(err)
               

noimage_jobs()
```

Comment: Where does `line` get set?

Comment: You could turn the answer you found into a function, and call that for every file.

Comment: @ Nick sorry about that.After with open(file_path, 'r') as myfile:); for line in myfile:

Comment: @ Emanuel, can you please let me know what needs to be changed ?

Comment: Any help would be appreciated?